# php issue when using image fader script

Tags: php

I am having trouble with the following piece of code. I believe it's an issue with incorrect use of single/double quotes, but cant figure it out, can anyone advise?

```
foreach ($page->images as $image) {
    echo '<img src= "<?php echo $image->url;?>" >';
}
```

Comment: Whats not working? and what are the values of $image

Answer (score 1):

No need to redclare PHP & echo.  So your code that looks like this:

```
foreach ($page->images as $image) {
  echo '<img src= "<?php echo $image->url;?>" >';
}
```

Should be this:

```
foreach ($page->images as $image) {
  echo '<img src= "' . $image->url . '" >';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP syntax rules. strings quoted with `'` do NOT interpolate variable values. Your script is dumping a literal `<`, `?`, `p`, `h`, etc... out to the browser.

You also can't run php code WITHIN a string.

Try

```
foreach(...) {
   echo "<img src='{$image->url}'>";
}
```

instead

Comment: No! Never interpolate variables in strings!

Answer (score 0):

try with this syntax :

```
echo '<img src="' , $image->url , '">';
```

you're already in php so no need to add `<?php` again in your `echo`

Comment: @JakeGould @cole-johnson Check http://www.php.net/echo , `echo` is a language construct that can take several parameters, the commas are valid, see http://codepad.org/lo5u1E5y

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead:

```
foreach ($page->images as $image) {

                echo "<img src= '{$image->url}' >";

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

variables inside single-quoted strings are not interpreted. You also don't need the php tags and echo within the string. Try changing

```
echo '<img src= "<?php echo $image->url;?>" >';
```

to

```
echo '<img src= "'.$image->url.'" >';
```